# Date and Time only partially visible in Big Sur

Tags: macos, menu-bar, big-sur, clock, do-not-disturb

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the date and time are dimmer than normal.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Date and time is now also Notification Center 'icon'. If it is dimmed it means that you have 'Do Not Disturb' active. To toggle between on/off DND hold ⌥ key while clicking on date/time.

If you don't like dimming then you should head to Dock & Menu Bar in Preferences. On left pane select 'Do Not Disturb' and tick 'Show in menu bar' and select 'when active'. By doing this tilted half-moon icon will be displayed on Status menu if DND is active and date/time will not be dimmed.