# Why is the date in my menu bar transparent?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Late at night, my menu bar looks like this:

[image: The date is transparent...]

Does anyone know why the date is transparent? It's really hard to read like this. Can I turn this off?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407474/350043](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407474/350043)

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for linking to that question.