# Highlight Menu Bar Clock in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur, menu-bar, clock

After upgrading my Mac to Big Sur (11.6), I noticed that my Menu Bar clock has a very faint color and makes it hard to read the time.

[image]

Is there a way to change this to bring older behavior? I don't see any options in the Menu bar settings to fix this.

[image]

Comment: This could be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407474/350043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending several hours browsing through various settings, I came across the below post.

`Opt` + `Click` on the Clock will change the highlight. `Opt` + `Click` again on the Clock will change the behavior back.

[image]

**Credits** - https://www.askdavetaylor.com/can-i-fix-or-change-the-menu-bar-clock-color-in-macos-big-sur/

Comment: Yeah, as pointed out in the comments underneath, the author missed the point - Opt/click toggles Do Not Disturb, which may have unintended consequences. See Aivar's linked answer above for the best way to do this.